# Range of $\frac{\log(x)}{x^{b}}$

Tags: calculus, elementary-functions

This is from Berkeley problems. Actual question is this

> For which positive numbers $a,b,~ a >1$ does the equation $\log_{a}(x)=x^{b}$ have positive solution for $x$?

For solving this we can rewrite the expression as $\log a= \frac{\log x}{x^b}$. Hence the problem reduces to this for what values of $x$  $\log a $ lies in the range of $f(x)= \frac{\log x}{x^b}$ the solution says range of  $f(x)= (\infty,\frac{1}{be})$. Using geogebra I can verify this. But how to find range of such functions? All I know is range of $\log x$ in $(-\infty,\infty)$ and range of $\frac{1}{x^b}$ in set of all non zero reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x) = x^{-b} \ln(x) $$
$$f'(x) = (-b)x^{-b-1} \ln(x) + x^{-b-1} =x^{-b-1} (1-b \ln(x))$$

So there will be a critical pt. where

$$  \ln(x)=\frac 1b \implies x=e^{1/b} $$

This will be the global max whenever $b>0$

The max value for $f(x)$ is

$$f(  e^{1/b}  ) = ( e^{1/b})^{-b} \ln(e^{1/b})=e^{-1}(1/b)=\frac 1{be}
$$

Answer (score 1):

To find the range of $f(x) = \frac{\log(x)}{x^b}$, it suffices to use the usual calculus techniques to confirm that:

- $y = f(x)$ has a vertical asymptote at $x = 0$
- there exists an $r$ such that $f(x)$ is increasing over $0 < x < r$, and that $f(x)$ is decreasing over $x > r$

Answer (score -1):

Differentiate the fuction .... then find its maxima..... in this case the function is increasing for x less than $e^{1/b}$. The corresponding y for this x is ${1/be}$. Hence this the max. Value of the function. Hence the range is ${-infinity}$ to ${1/be}$.

Comment: Perhaps you were rushing to post an answer, but the result suffers from a succession of sentence fragments.  Please edit to use complete sentences, and take the time to work in some of the details of your computation.

Comment: Theres no use of doing -1 as  the one who has asked it has a REPUTATION of 544 and you have a reputation of around 22k..... so i expect that you people have brains enough to understand it....

Comment: I'm not a downvoter for either the Answer or the Question (yet).  My comment was a suggestion about improving the Answer for the sake of future Readers.  Math.SE has a goal of curating excellent content for the sake of learning mathematics at all levels.